# Render information for each users nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In the current project, I'm working on. Users can enter the amount they want to invest and I have associated each user to the amount they input. The issue is that I want to display the history of the amount they choose to each user.

Here is the Schema for users to choose the amount they want to invest

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Package1Schema = new Schema({
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    investor:{
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        email: String,
        firstname: String,
        lastname: String
    },
    
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
}
});

const Package1 = mongoose.model('Package1', Package1Schema);

module.exports = Package1;
```

Here is the router code

```
//Investment History
router.get("/investment-history/", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>{
    res.render("investment-history", {
        firstname: req.package2.firstname,
        lastname: req.package2.lastname,
        amount: req.package2.amount
    });
});
```

Here is the ejs code

```
<tbody>
<% package2.forEach(function(package2){ %>
    <tr>
     <td>Package 2</td>
     <td><%= package2.firstname %></td>
     <td><%= package2.lastname %></td>
     <td><%= package2.amount %></td>
     <td>Pending</td>
<%});%>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbqyf.png)

Comment: Can you add the `ejs` code? It looks like you have added router code instead of ejs code

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for the head up. I have edited and add the ejs code I used. Will be looking forward to providing your help. Thanks.

Comment: What is `req.package2` and where is it coming from? Also where are you querying DB for user investments? Also, where is the userId of the user you want to show the investment history of? Is it in `req.user`. Are you populating `req.user` in `ensureAuthenticated` method?

Comment: I have a package schema which is associated to the user schema. the req.package is coming from the Package schema and I want to get the current data of the user which is associate with the package schema. req.user is populated in esureAuthenticated method.